# Socket Server getting 500ms round-trip times locally

Tags: php, javascript, sockets, websocket

I have a basic Ubuntu virtual machine set up here in our office (Ubuntu 12.04) with a basic LAMP stack installed.

I wrote a PHP socket server using `socket_create`.  See code:

```
$this -> master = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Failed: socket_create()");
    socket_set_option($this -> master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1) or die("Failed: socket_option()");
    socket_bind($this -> master, $addr, $port) or die("Failed: socket_bind()");
    socket_listen($this -> master, 20) or die("Failed: socket_listen()");
```

All seemed good. We can ping the server locally and get less than <1ms ping times,  but when we use Chrome's new `WebSocket` javascript API, we're getting messages consistently sent and received at 500ms apart. Literally like 497, 501, 503, 500ms, etc.

Any suggestions what could be causing this?

Comment: What kind of WebSocket server are you using?

Comment: It's just php executed in a while loop on the server. php -q scriptname.php.

Comment: I also wrote a similar solution in Node.js after this, and was still getting the identical 500ms ping times, which lead me to look for another reason. Turns out it was our virus/firewall protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the ESET Smart Security firewall protection. Disabling the "HTTP/HTTPS Scanner" immediately caused the speeds to drop down to 60ms like they should have been!